# "NoMethodError in TasksController#update" -- why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm learning Rails (so this is probably a stupid error).   I'm trying to write an edit screen that updates a parent and its children at the same time.  When I hit save I get:

```
NoMethodError in TasksController#update
undefined method `to_sym' for #<Arel::Attributes::Integer:0x00000004d11970>
```

I can't figure out what has caused this and where/what this integer object is.  Can anyone give me any pointers?

**EDIT: I can make this work if I start from scratch with a new Rails project.  The parameters that are raising the error are the ones under the key "flactions_attributes".  There seem to be some values missing from that, but that's not the problem**.

#### Detail

The parent model is Task, the child is Flaction.  (Take it from me, you don't want to name a table 'action' in Rails...)

The Error page also helpfully shows the params hash (please pardon my 'comedy' test data.):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"QS1gVSz+LKNIyBsIdnSMVfciBA+3j0nFK37477A7mps=",
 "task"=>{"name"=>"Finish secret lair",
 "description"=>"",
 "flactions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Choose a colour scheme",
 "notes"=>"Ask The Voices?",
 "id"=>"80"},
 "1"=>{"name"=>"Pick a name",
 "notes"=>"Something with skulls in it?",
 "id"=>"81"}}},
 "x"=>"3",
 "y"=>"14",
 "id"=>"53"}
```

Here's the update method in the controller.  AFAICS it's completely vanilla:

```
def update
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
      format.html { redirect_to(@task, :notice => 'Task was successfully updated.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

So: @task.update_attributes finds an integer and tries to run to_sym on it.  The only thing I pass to update_attributes is params, and there are no integer keys there.  How do I work out what is going on?

Here's the _form file, FWIW:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>

  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="<%= @task.hold ? 'task held' : 'task' %>" >

    <div class="field name">
      <%= f.text_field :name, size: 20 %>

      <span class="buttons">
        <%= if @task.hold
              link_to image_tag('unhold-icon.png', alt: 'Un-hold'), change_hold_task_path(@task)
            else
              link_to image_tag('hold-icon.png', alt: 'Hold'), change_hold_task_path(@task)
        end %>

        <%= link_to image_tag('delete-icon.png', alt: 'Delete'), @task, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="field desc">
      <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 3, cols: 95 %>
    </div>


    <table>
      <% f.fields_for :flactions do |a| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="field"> <%= a.text_field :name %> </td>
          <td class="field"> <%= a.text_area :notes, rows: 2, columns: 40 %> </td>

          <td class="buttons">
            <%= link_to image_tag("up-icon-small.png", alt: 'Move Up'), move_flaction_path(a.object, direction: "up") %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("down-icon-small.png", alt: 'Move Down'), move_flaction_path(a.object, direction: "down") %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("delete-icon-small.png", alt: 'Delete'), a.object,  :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end # f.fields_for %>

    </table>

    <%= image_submit_tag('save-icon.png', alt: 'Save') %>
  </div> <!-- of div.task or div.task_held -->

<% end %>
```

EDIT: Stack trace, as requested:

```
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1267:in `block in     expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1266:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1266:in `expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:225:in `build_where'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:76:in `where'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb:124:in `apply_finder_options'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:143:in `all'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:364:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:254:in `flactions_attributes='
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `block in attributes='
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `attributes='
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:131:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:130:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:62:in `block in update'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:264:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:264:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:191:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:61:in `update'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__950750868564864989__process_action__1833593346352443574__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2-p180/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2-p180/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2-p180/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for looking at this...

Comment: What's the matter with having an `Action` model with a corresponding `actions` table?

Comment: Maybe I screwed up.  But I found that `params` used the key 'action' in a special way.  So you can have a table called action, but the values of the fields never make it into the `params` hash.

Comment: Is the complete view code? because I am not able to find the method=put in the form_for and attributes like x and y in the params hash seems to be missing.

Comment: @Felix -- yes, that's the complete view code.   The x and y keys are there in the params hash -- incidentally, what are they for?  I do wish that Rails was better documented...

Comment: @Andy, that's not a Rails thing. x and y are sent by browsers like Firefox when there is an image-based submit button. It's the pixel location of the cursor.

Comment: It does that because params :action and params :controller are used for routing...

Comment: @Taryn: bad design, though.  If the table data was all held in a lower level, in a key called 'form_data', say, then it couldn't happen.

Comment: Yeah. Rails is full of stuff like that... all "undocumented features" :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT! This wins my personal running prize for the least helpful Rails error ... so far.

The problem was caused because I'd written my own Task.flactions method in the model.  Once I deleted that, it worked fine.  So, one more thing to remember never to do again: don't override methods that Rails creates for you.

Incidentally, as far as I can tell, the ONLY place parent-child forms in Rails 3 are currently documented is in `ri form_for`.  There are examples there, too.  Worth looking at.